# AzureML Model.profile() timeout without ever running the model

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

When trying to profile our AzureML model we run into a timeout. According to the log statements, **the model is initialized** but the **run function is never called**.

The dataset provided contains one column ("profile_requests") and 100 samples of serialized json that the model usually consumes. Both model and score.py work fine when deploying via Model.deploy (see below).

Why is the run function never called?

```
profile = Model.profile(ws, 
    profile_name='my-profile-name',
    models=[latest_model], 
    inference_config=InferenceConfig(
                                    entry_script='score.py', 
                                    source_directory="deployment",
                                    environment=Environment.get(ws, "my_environment")), 
    input_dataset=processed_dataset,
    cpu=2,
    memory_in_gb=3)
```

```
{...,
 'error': {'code': 'ModelTestTimeOut',
  'statusCode': 500,
  'message': 'The model did not finish the test within the allowed time: 30 min. Error logs URL: https://link-to-logfile',
  'details': []},
 'errorLogsUri': 'https://link-to-logfile'}
```

Profiling log file:

```
==========Logs from model deployed to container with 2 cpu and 3 GB memory==========
[...]
Invoking user's init function
Model loaded.
Users's init has completed successfully
Scoring timeout setting is not found. Use default timeout: 3600000 ms
```

One sample from the DataFrame (`sample_event=processed_dataset.to_pandas_dataframe().loc[0,"profile_requests"]`)

```
'{"allevents": [{"temperature": 103.76252626686478, "ambienttemperature": 20.763083531178108, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:02", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 104.00700291712167, "ambienttemperature": 20.77088671236806, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:07", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.73538818128196, "ambienttemperature": 20.927115571418366, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:12", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.26993925975171, "ambienttemperature": 20.977784248757075, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:17", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.47584351197627, "ambienttemperature": 20.528207412934027, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:22", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.53497833736942, "ambienttemperature": 21.176729435416277, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:27", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.33621482217512, "ambienttemperature": 21.083552645791112, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:32", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.13542993745558, "ambienttemperature": 20.80351544511668, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:37", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.45331951321728, "ambienttemperature": 21.404335822865523, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:42", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.52506972734126, "ambienttemperature": 20.51882900857312, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:47", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.61395300883524, "ambienttemperature": 21.110307039511532, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:52", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}, {"temperature": 103.49871551548077, "ambienttemperature": 21.133206947070178, "timeCreated": "2020-04-02T12:07:57", "ConnectionDeviceId": "milkbottleEdge", "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637211838651873534"}]}'
```

Running the sample against the deployed webservice that uses the same environment and score.py `service.run(sample_event)` works as expected.

```
{'result': False,
 'ConnectionDeviceId': 'milkbottleEdge',
 'timeCreatedStart': '2020-04-02T12:07:02',
 'timeCreatedEnd': '2020-04-02T12:07:57',
 'hasError': False,
 'errorMessage': None}
```